# What ingredients smell good when microwaved?

Tags: microwave, smell

My workplace's breakroom has a microwave next to the coffee machine. The room ventilation isn't great and the smell of microwaved food is often still noticeable even a couple hours after lunch, when we go back to get coffee.

Are there any ingredient that smells good when microwaved?

I'm especially looking for something easy to add like sauces, herbs, or spices. And with a smell that doesn't turn unpleasant even when "cold". For example garlic smell is great when you're about to eat, but quickly turns gross afterwards. I was thinking of putting some cut mint on my food, but it doesn't go well with most dishes.

Comment: Not sure what you are after. Do you want _your_ food to smell good? Good to you or to someone else? Do you want to _mask_ the smell you find unpleasant by microwaving something else?

Comment: @mustaccio I'd like my food to smell good. There are only 3 people using this breakroom, so changing what I eat will make a big difference.

Comment: Good is subjective from person to person, and place to place.

Answer (score 1):

Smell usually come from splatters, even minuscule amount of splatters.

Make sure you **properly clean** all surfaces inside and outside the microwave after you (and colleagues) use it.

You can also try to microwave some diluted lemon or white vinegar.

Leave the door ajar so that everything stays dry after cleaning it.

You can also use a plugin air freshener in the room.

If you have a cleaning service, make sure they actually clean the kitchen and microwave.